# Rails CSV import with weird format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

I am new to RoR

I know how to upload a CSV file into my database, but the CSV file which I have is in a weird format, instead of headers in a header column, the header is in front of the data like this:

```
Name:Peanut,Age:17,State:NY
Name:Donkey,Age:23,State:NY
Name:Flower,Age:18,State:NY
```

Another problem is some rows don't have all the data so isn't in the same order like this:

```
Name:Peanut,Age:17,State:NY
Name:Donkey,State:NY
Age:18,State:NY
```

I guess I would use a loop in the model file to first extract the header but don't have an idea on where to start nor how it should look. Please help?

Comment: are the headers the same values as your database?

Comment: @Anthony yes, they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create objects, you really just pass in a hash of values like this:

```
User.create(name: "Some name", age: 18)
```

You can use a ruby script like this:

```
require 'CSV'
CSV.foreach('users.csv') do |line|
  user = line.each_with_object({}) do |val, hash|
    vals = val.split(':')
    hash[vals.first] = vals.last
  end
  User.create(user)
end
```

I'm just building a hash of values that look like this:

```
{"Name"=>"Peanut", "Age"=>"17", "State"=>"NY"}
{"Name"=>"Donkey", "Age"=>"23", "State"=>"NY"}
{"Name"=>"Flower", "Age"=>"18", "State"=>"NY"}
```

I'm sending those values into the `User.create` call.  Regarding your missing data, it would only be a problem if you have validations on your model (ie. `validates :age, presence: true`) otherwise, if you don't give it a value it will just be nil in your database (which would be accurate if you're not being provided the data).